# Is Google Web Toolkit is fine to develop database based web application?

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee

Is Google Web Toolkit is fine to develop database based web application or do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks to answerers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a heavy Database based web application, nothing beats [Grails](http://grails.org/). Check out this [tutorial by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/). It will show you the power of Grails and how easy it is to develop database based web applications in minutes. I love GWT and smartGwt, but will go for them over pure grails only if there is a lot of non-database based front end (client side) logic.

If you do not have a programming language of choice (Grails is groovy based, which is based on Java), you could even look at [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) which was the inspiration for Grails itself.

Alternately, you can add both grails and gwt in the mix by using this [gwt grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gwt) so that you have a powerful database integration, as well as a powerful front end developer. (I haven't used this though)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you will need to create your own [RPC service](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) to get records from server to client and to deliver modified records back the server. But it isn't difficult at all.

Alternatively you could also use [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/), which is an extension for GWT with more widgets, etc. They have data bound objects but in free version would would need to create your own data sources. If you decide to buy a license they seem to have [database integration out of the box](http://www.smartclient.com/product/).

And additional note to consider with SmartGWT is that it has relatively big download size - about 3MB uncompressed and almost 1MB compressed (HTTP server should compresse it; it is in HTTP standard and it is transparent). So if it is going to be a service in public internet it might get quite long to load (often exceeding magic 8 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

I had been working on GWT (Google Web Toolkit) for 1.5 years and learned that its a perfect platform for developing web application which uses backend database for its operation unless you have the right skill sets working on your project and a basic design which is developed according to the requirement of your project.